# Fancy Apps image gallery with comments

Tags: ajax, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I currently have a basic Fancy Box gallery (link calls larger image and title that is then displayed in the Fancy box).

How/ What would be the best way to integrate a comments system into this? Each photo has member comments but I need a way to show these next to the photo in Fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

You may  consider my fancybox "a la" Facebook  ;)

http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxALAfacebook_26Mar12.html

You could insert any html in the right area.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, Just like you display each picture with their independent comments, you will just display them into a larger box on click on a picture. just like facebook. Use whatever ajax u are currently using in the page into the box.